# Python Regex to match and exclude certain content

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to exclude some content from a string. Here is an example:

```
Sony Xperia Z2 m/Smartwatch 2
```

and:

```
Sony Xperia Z2 + headphones
```

I want to get only

```
Sony Xperia Z2
```

in both cases.

I have been able to match the string i want to get rid of with this but how do i select the inverse?
What i got so far:

```
 m/([a-zA-Z 0-9]*)
```

**Edit:** I have added another case.

Comment: How do *you know* that's the bit you want? Everything up to `' m/'`?

Comment: After your edit it is not clear what text you want to discard from input.

Comment: Good point both of you. I want the name of the brand and phone. not all the other additional information for each line. Updated my question to clarify for future readers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using regex split**

```
re.split(r" m/| \+ ", yourString)[0]
```

This will work with both of your examples:

```
string1 = "Sony Xperia Z2 m/Smartwatch 2"
print re.split(" m/| \+ ", string1)[0]
# output: Sony Xperia Z2

string2 = "Sony Xperia Z2 + headphones"
print re.split(" m/| \+ ", string2)[0]
# output: Sony Xperia Z2
```

And if you have more separator characters, you can add them to the pattern of the [`split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split) function.

You can also use `re.split(...)[1]` to retrieve the second part of your string:

```
string1 = "Sony Xperia Z2 m/Smartwatch 2"
print re.split(" m/| \+ ", string1)[1]
# output: Smartwatch 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
>>> s = 'Sony Xperia Z2 m/Smartwatch 2'
>>> re.sub(r'\s*m/.*$', '', s)
'Sony Xperia Z2'
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using Regex**

```
>>> re.findall(r"[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+(?= m/)", "Sony Xperia Z2 m/Smartwatch 2")
['Sony Xperia Z2']
```

---

```
>>> re.findall(r"[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+(?= m/)", "Sony Xperia Z2 m/Smartwatch 2")[0]
'Sony Xperia Z2'
```

**Using Split**

```
>>> "Sony Xperia Z2 m/Smartwatch 2".split(" m/")[0]
'Sony Xperia Z2'
```

Comment: Neat solution to use Split. :)

Comment: @OleHenrikSkogstrøm `split` would be the most prefered solution

Answer (score 0):

Something like :

```
test = 'Sony Xperia Z2 m/Smartwatch 2'
res = re.search('m/([a-zA-Z 0-9]*)', test)
cleanstr = test.replace(res.group(), '')
print cleanstr
```

And you got `Sony Xperia Z2`